# Proof of Smith Normal Form theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, smith-normal-form

It is a homework asking me to prove the Smith Normal Form theorem, stating that

> If $R$ is a PID, and $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix over $R$, then there
>   exists invertible matrices $P, Q$ such that $PAQ$ is diagonal.

There is a hint at the end of the question, saying that let $F=R^n$ and $\alpha$ be the module homomorphism from $F$ to $F$ with the matrix $A$. First we show $F=U\oplus\ker(\alpha)$ for some $U\cong R^m$ with $m\leqslant n$. I have done this.

The hint continues and says we then find a basis of $\{u_1,\cdots,u_m\}$ for $U$, $\{u_{m+1},\cdots,u_n\}$ for $\ker(\alpha)$, and $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ for $F$, such that $\alpha$ is represented as a diagonal matrix w.r.t. basis $\{u_1,\cdots,u_n\}$ and $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$.

However, I cannot construct such basis. Can anyone help?

---

Update:

R is a commutative ring, because it is the homework of the course Commutative Algebra.

Comment: Good luck with your exercise. When you have succeeded, you should tell your teacher that this is not the Smith normal form theorem. The Hermite normal form theorem is a nice intermediate step on the road to your homework problem (and to the Smith normal form). Both theorems are exercises in row and column operations on matrices. You carry out invertible row and column operations that reduce the number of off-diagonal entries (so you can swap rows and columns and add or subtract multiples of one row or column from another).